# Difference between uint8_t and unspecified int for large matrices

Tags: c++, memory

I have a matrix that is over 17,000 x 14,000 that I'm storing in memory in C++.  The values will never get over 255 so I'm thinking I should store this matrix as a uint8_t type instead of a regular int type.  Will the regular int type will assume the native word size (64 bit so 8 bytes per cell) even with an optimizing compiler?  I'm assuming I'll use 8x less memory if I store the array as uint8_t?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and I do realize uint8_t may be slower, but the goal is to support larger arrays in memory then the example I gave.

Comment: The conventional type to hold 0...255 is `unsigned char`. This is similar to the type `uint_least8_t`. Because `uint8_t` must be _exactly_  8 bits, the compiler may need to insert extra instructions to actively truncate values higher than 255. That's obviously less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard doesn't specify the exact size of `int` other than it's at least the size of `short`. On some 64-bit architectures (for example many Linux and Solaris x86 systems I work with) `int` is 32 bits and `long` is 64 bits. The exact size of each type will of course vary by compiler/hardware.

The best way to find out is to use `sizeof(int)` on your system and see how big it is. If you have enough RAM using the native type may in fact be significantly faster than the `uint8_t`.

Comment: Nope, `long` is 32, `long long` is 64 on both x86 and amd64.

Comment: @wormsparty:  On my system (x86_64 Linux Linux), `long` is 64 bits.  I am pretty sure Mark B is correct about "most" 64-bit platforms.

Comment: @wormsparty: can you clarify what you mean by "long is 32 on ... amd64"? It's not really an "architecture" issue, since there's more than one ABI on the same architecture, so it varies by OS even on the same CPU. Anyway, your one example cannot contradict a claim that "most" 64-bit architectures have a particular property, 64 bit Windows is one member of what Mark claims is a minority.

Comment: @wormsparty [The data type names have nothing to do with processor architecture](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models). They are defined by the OS and Mark B's answer is correct for most Unix / Linux and Mac systems.

Comment: @wormsparty: Not on my x86 computer with my OS and my compilers. `long` is 64 bits. In fact, `long long` is not an official part of C++03. It is a C99 extension that most C++ compilers long ago added as an extension to C++03. It is a part of C++11, but there aren't any fully-compliant C++11 compilers out there yet.

Comment: On any machine today and in the next decade, even if `int` is faster than `uint8_t`, `uint8_t[14000][17000]` is going to be faster than `int[14000][17000]`. By a significant margin, even. Wasting so many bits in all cache levels never pays off.

Answer (score 3):

If you doubt this, you could have just tried it.

Of course it will be smaller.

However, it wholly depends on your usage patterns which will be faster. Profile! Profile! Profile!

Reasons for unexpected performance considerations:

- alignment issues
- elements sharing cache lines (could be positive on sequential access; negative in multicore scenarios)
- increased need for locking on atomic reads/writes (in case of threading)
- reduced applicability of certain optimized MIPS instructions (? - I'm not up-to-date with details here; also a very good optimizing compiler *might* simply register-allocate temporaries of the right size)
- other, unrelated border conditions, originating from the surrounding code

Answer (score 1):

Even the best optimizing compiler is not going to do an analysis of the values of the data that you put into your matrix and assume (anthropomorphizing here) "Hmmm. He said `int` but everything is between 0 and 255. I'm going to make that an array of `uint8_t`."

The compiler can interpret some keywords such as `register` and `inline` as suggestions rather than mandates. Types on the other hand are mandates. You told the compiler to use `int` so the compiler must use `int`. So switching to a `uint8_t` matrix will save you a considerable amount of memory here.